# How to display progress bar during span size is changed in Recycler View GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I am using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayout` to display products. I have a button which changes the span size when clicked. I have used `gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup` to dynamically change the span size. Everything is working fine but when I click on the button it takes some time to change the span size. I want to show a progress bar during this process. How can I do that?

```
 public void onGridViewClick() {
        if (isGridViewEnabled){
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    switch (adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getType()) {
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.SEARCH_ITEM: return 2;
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.SWAN_ITEM:  return 2;
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.OFFER_EXPIRED: return 2;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });
            isGridViewEnabled=false;

        }else {
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    switch (adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getType()) {
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.SEARCH_ITEM: return 1;
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.SWAN_ITEM:  return 2;
                        case BaseGoodkartSearchResultModel.OFFER_EXPIRED: return 2;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });
            isGridViewEnabled=true;
        }
        
    }
```

[image: screenshot of activity , products are switched to linear when button is clicked]

Comment: What do you mean by "it takes some time"? Is it longer than a single layout pass of recyclerview?

Comment: https://cutt.ly/9ciULzN please check this video

Answer (score -1):

Just Show a alert dialog box with progress bar (Default Progress bar like circle) in it when user click on grid view and dismiss after view is loaded.

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog;  
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progresslayout);// This Layout just contain a simple progress bar
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.dismiss();// to dismiss when layout loaded
```

Comment: I have already tried this , it is not working , how I will come to know that recycler view has now successfully changed the layout  ? (so that i can dismiss the progress bar)

Comment: Just simply start a thread which check your isGridViewEnabled and dismiss